# Django CONN_MAX_AGE not working on Azure MSSQL DB

Tags: sql-server, django, azure-sql-database, django-database

I am trying to use the next settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pw',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE' : 600,
    }
}
```

But calling my view where I have 2 simple queries takes always almost the same time - around 1.3sec. Calling the same view but without the queries it takes 100ms. So I think my problem is that every time it opens a new connection to the SQL DB.

Any suggestion why CONN_MAX_AGE doesn't want to work?

Best Regards,
Kristian Veselinov

Comment: I have forwarded this question to the author of the adapter. Will keep you posted with his response.

Comment: hello Kristian, what behavior do you see when you change the value of con_max_age? Do you have an error messages that you can share?

Comment: Hello, I have no error messages. The problem is just in the slow executing on the first query in the view and every query after the first is a lot faster.
I saw the difference easily when debugging.

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pyodbc?

Comment: I am using django-pyodbc-azure

Answer (score 0):

Azure has many error with django (and i see it has many error with other services)
Ex: error with path (replace url)
error with filter,... create_at__month (use for loop to get month and compare ~~)
can't close mysql connections (i can't fix it ~~)

I think you should use heroku, it easy to deploy, no error as azure, faster, and have plan free to test